# How to write a custom java rule for XSLT files

Tags: pmd

I'm writing a custom rule for xslt files. The rule is to check for the presence of any tags within comments in xslt files. I did this same check for xml files as shown below. What (rule) class to extend and what method to override for making this work for xslt files?

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleContext;
import net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.xml.ast.XmlNode;
import net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.xml.rule.AbstractDomXmlRule;
import org.w3c.dom.Comment;

public class CommentedCodeRule extends AbstractDomXmlRule {
    private static final Pattern TAG = Pattern.compile("<\\w+>");

    @Override
    protected void visit(XmlNode node, Comment comment, RuleContext ctx) {
        if (hasTag(comment)) {
            addViolation(ctx, node);
        }
        super.visit(node, comment, ctx);
    }

    private static boolean hasTag(Comment comment) {
        return TAG.matcher(comment.getData()).find();
    }
}
```

UPDATE - Adding the ruleset xml used

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ruleset name="quickstart"
         xmlns="http://pmd.sourceforge.net/ruleset/2.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://pmd.sourceforge.net/ruleset/2.0.0 https://pmd.sourceforge.io/ruleset_2_0_0.xsd">

    <description>"Commented-out code" check.</description>

    <rule name="CommentedCodeXml"
          language="xml"
          since="3.0"
          message="Found commented-out code."
          class="CommentedCodeRule"
          externalInfoUrl="">
        <description>
            Production code should not contain any commented-out code. It suggests an incomplete implementation, 
            and consequently, decreases confidence in the code.
        </description>
        <priority>3</priority>
    </rule>
    <rule name="CommentedCodeXsl"
          language="xsl"
          since="3.0"
          message="Found commented-out code."
          class="CommentedCodeRule"
          externalInfoUrl="">
        <description>
            Production code should not contain any commented-out code. It suggests an incomplete implementation, 
            and consequently, decreases confidence in the code.
        </description>
        <priority>3</priority>
    </rule>
</ruleset>
```

Comment: That exact same rule should work, but with one caveat. The XML ruleset that defines the rule needs to set the attribute `language="xsl"` (by default it will only target XML files). If you want the rule to apply to both XML AND XSLT files, you need 2 almost identical <rule> nodes in the ruleset, just changing the names (need to be unique), and on one setting the language to xsl.

Comment: @Johnco, there is one problem with adding 2 almost identical rules one for xsl and one for xml both referencing the same java custom rule class. When a xml file with a violation is provided as input, I end up getting 2 violations one from the xml rule and one from the xsl rule. Not sure why pmd applies the xsl rule also to the xml file.

Comment: it shouldn't… if you can update your question I may be able to identify the problem.

Comment: @Johnco, added the ruleset used with both xml and xsl rules